# PHPUnit mock method with different args in do while

Tags: php, phpunit

```
Class Foo {
    function getContacts() {
        $batchSize = 1000;
        do {
            $apiContacts = $client->getContactsSuppressedSinceDate(
                $this->getFromTime(),
                $batchSize,
                $skip
            );
            $skip += $batchSize;
        } while (count($apiContacts) === $batchSize);
    }
}
```

I want to unit test this while loop, but I want to override the batch size to be much smaller than 1000, to be manageable.

```
        $clientMock->expects($this->exactly(3))
            ->method('getContactsSuppressedSinceDate')
            ->withConsecutive(
                [$fromTime, $this->equalTo(3), 0],
                [$fromTime, $this->equalTo(3), 3],
                [$fromTime, $this->equalTo(0), 6]
            )
            ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
                $this->getSuppressedContacts(),
                $this->getSuppressedContacts(),
                new \stdClass()
            );
```

[`$this->getSuppressedContacts()` returns an array of 3 'contacts' for testing.]

However I can't get it to override that `$batchSize` variable. Can I?

```
Expectation failed for method name is "getContactsSuppressedSinceDate" when invoked 3 time(s)
Parameter 1 for invocation #0 Client::getContactsSuppressedSinceDate('2021-11-18T12:17:47+00:00', 1000, 0) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that 1000 matches expected 3.
```

Comment: There is no way you can change that as you did not expose that variable in any way. You should move it to the method as a method parameter, and have a default of `1000`, but if you want to change it allow the user, you could then test it in your test.

Comment: Yep. You're right. I need to pull out that $batchSize variable to enable me to set it when running the test.